# Book/tutorial that teaches how to make programs that are easy to maintain and are less coupled?

Tags: php, cakephp, maintainability, decoupling

I'm a PHP programmer and I really want to increase the quality of my code and most importantly I want to be better at programming.

What book, tutorial or article would you guys suggest that I read that teaches how to make programs that are less coupled and easy to maintain? Are there any specific tips for PHP especially for the CakePHP framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This heavily depends on your skill level and what you want to achieve in concrete. Generally one can say that you’ll get a better programmer by programming and programming and programming… CakePHP already forces you to program a little bit more modular and decoupled. So what’s your question? Which parts of your code aren’t good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer) is a good fit here. A little high level, but lots and lots of important, valuable, and clear wisdom. It's language-agnostic.

As for PHP, personally I'm not much of a fan, I think there are other languages that are much better at supporting decoupling. Python, Java, C#, Scala — even JavaScript, with a [CommonJS](http://commonjs.org/) runtime such as [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

That said, you asked about PHP, so my advice would be to find some well-designed Open Source apps and see how they did it. Unfortunately I don't know any specifically, but there must be some.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually learning Rails and as I go on I realized how coupled my past code is in PHP hence the reason for asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

As someone in a similar situation, I'm finding PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book/)) very helpful.